# How to get console logs from new PowerShell session in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

My application build script has to be executed in PowerShell as administrator. I have tried as below in Jenkins build section in PowerShell.

```
$pro = Start-Process powershell -Verb runas -ArgumentList /c, .\buildPackages.cmd -PassThru

if ($pro.ExitCode -ne 0) {
    Write-Warning "$_ exited with status code $($pro.ExitCode)"
    exit 1
}
```

My build is running in a new PowerShell window which is opened as administrator with the above commands, but I am not able to get the logs in Jenkins console output.
Is there anyway I can display the build logs which is in the new PowerShell window to Jenkins console?

Comment: Don't run in a new window (`-NoNewWindow`). You may also want to wait for the process to terminate (`-Wait`). And since you're running a batch script anyway, use `cmd.exe` instead of `powershell.exe`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, I had tried -NoNewWindow and it was giving me error Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1 . It didnt work with -Verb.

Comment: Then you probably need to write the output of the elevated process to a temp file and cat that file after the process terminates.